# How to access application in Tomcat with Context path

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I have a web application which is developed with J2EE, GWT and hosting on Tomcat(version-7.0). I have webapp called "Courses"
which is plcaed in tomcat/webapps folder. I am accessing my "courses" application by using the following Url:
http://localhost:8085/Courses.
In my courses application i have so many slices like "physics", "maths" etc.I need to access "physics" 
Now i want to access my application by entering the Url:

http://localhost:8085/Courses/physics

How can I run my courses application by entering the above URL.

Comment: Where does the "physics" come from? If your .war file (or folder) is named `Courses` then that is your app name, and …/Courses is the correct URL. Actually that is default behavior. You can specify another URL if you must. Or is "physics" just a slice of data within your Courses web app, as well as "poetry", "geology", and "art history" courses? Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you@BasilBourque, physics is one of part in my Courses appliocation

Comment: I have updated my question, some body Please look into it and let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

In GWT you should use GWT's history mechanism for this.

The URL you wish http://localhost:8085/Courses/physics isn't really possible using GWT (or you must create multiple modules but that seems a big overkill for your situation).

But you could have an url like : http://localhost:8085/Courses#physics

Check : http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html